# child and parent nodes presentation in html and css

Tags: html, css

I `iterate` some `objects` / text nodes or options I should say by a server side language and make up the html.

Each node may have a `child` or a `parent` node, and some options like checkboxes and radio buttons.

Now the problem I am facing is how to show the **child-parent relations ship** of those nodes.

I want to make each child not be placed **a little on the right side of its parent node.**

The problem is to make the `html / css` **know** the parent of the child node and make the **node move a bit right** side **`from`** the parents left border. I want the check boxes to remain in one vertical line order despite the child parent horizontal movement.

I would prefer using `tables TDs` over `UL` or `OL LI` but the question is. how to construct a strategy.

Example

```
text                    check box     check box     check box
text                    check box     check box     check box
text                    check box     check box     check box
  child text            check box     check box     check box
  child text            check box     check box     check box
    child text          check box     check box     check box
    child text          check box     check box     check box
      child text        check box     check box     check box
  child text            check box     check box     check box
text                    check box     check box     check box
text                    check box     check box     check box
  child text            check box     check box     check box
```

Comment: I really cant come to a solution. despite I have done much html css things

Comment: Use divs in your css. For <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>, in your css you can set the position for .parent, and .parent .child

Comment: I am having many suggestions by others. use tables as its tabular data, use ULs as it will give each child some margin to right. use divs, etc.  well there is not one working solution

Comment: From what I understood, it's pretty much a CSS selector thing? Like `parent > child`?

Comment: Show us your "not working solutions"

Comment: No,  a node is a node. its also a child of its parent and also a parent of its children.

Comment: Check this out. Maybe you can work on something based on this idea: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/nested-expandable-folders/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned it into a pen: http://codepen.io/pjetr/pen/JjCha

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="label">text 1</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="label">text 1.1</span>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span class="label">text 1.1.1</span>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
ul ul {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
ul input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. so tables is not a good choice and ULs is the way to go?